# Watir not locating tags in simple HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir-webdriver

I just started using Ruby and Webdriver to process strings of HTML. I waded through the learning curve, but either I am still doing something wrong or Watir's consistency is meh.

I am trying to get Watir to locate a couple of span tags because I want the text in between them. I can **puts** the HTML into my console just fine. I can see the tags I want. For some reason, my every attempt to path to them returns nil.[image]

Comment: FWIW: it's much easier to reproduce issues if the (minimal amount of) HTML and watir-webdriver code is present in the question.  Screenshots create more hoops  to jump through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is returning `nil`. You are doing a `puts`. The value of the `puts` is `nil`. The result of what you passed to `puts` is on the line right before `nil`. Try removing the `puts` and you should get the object directly.

Comment: That moment you feel like a complete derp. I have been staring at this for 30 minutes and never spotted that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The output is being interpreted incorrectly. The `nil` is the value returned from calling `puts`. It has nothing to do with Watir or the element being interacted with. You will see the same thing with other objects:

```
puts "test"
#=> "test"
#=> nil
```

Watir only goes and locates the element when you ask it to do something with it. For example,

```
browser.span(class: 'ShipmentBreadcrumb')
```

Simply creates an instance of a Watir::Span. It does not look for the element on the page or try to retrieve any data about it.  It isn't until you call something on the instance that it goes and looks for the element.

```
puts browser.span(class: 'ShipmentBreadcrumb')
#=> #<Watir::Span>
#=> nil
puts browser.span(class: 'ShipmentBreadcrumb').text
#=> "Sporting Goods"
#=> nil
```